# How to add an extra row to a custom lookup query?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I created a custom lookup on the ProdBom table and it just displays the BOM items for a given production order so that a user can select only items listed on the BOM.  I also want them to be able to select the produced BOM item (ProdTable.ItemId) in the list (1 extra item).  How could I do this?

Here is my current lookup:

```
static void lookupItemIdBOMSubset(FormStringControl   _ctrl,
                                  ProdId              _prodId)
{
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup  = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tablenum(ProdBOM), _ctrl);
    Query                   query           = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource    qbds            = query.addDataSource(tablenum(ProdBOM));
    ;

    qbds.addRange(fieldnum(ProdBOM, ProdId)).value(queryValue(_prodId));
    qbds.addSortField(fieldnum(ProdBOM, LineNum), SortOrder::Ascending);

    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);

    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ProdBOM, LineNum));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ProdBOM, bomId));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ProdBOM, ItemId), true);
    sysTableLookup.addLookupMethod(tablemethodstr(ProdBOM, itemName));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ProdBOM, ProdLineType));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ProdBOM, InventTransId));

    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a temp version of ProdBOM, populate it with the necessary information and use the buffer to perform the lookup:

```
ProdBom         tmpProdBom,
                prodBom;
ProdTable       prodTable;
;

//Set table as temp buffer
tmpProdBom.setTmp();

//First record, insert into temp buffer
select prodTable where prodTable.prodId = _prodId;

tmpProdBom.lineNum = 0;
tmpProdBom.bomId   = "";
tmpProdBom.ItemId  = prodTable.itemId;
//...etc for each field you have/want to be available
tmpProdBom.insert();

//Insert the rest of the records
while select prodBom where prodBom.ProdId = _prodId
{
    tmpProdBom.lineNum = prodBom.lineNum;
    tmpProdBom.bomId   = prodBom.bomId;
    //...etc for each field you want available
    tmpProdBom.insert();
}

sysTableLookup.parmTmpBuffer(tmpProdBom);

sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(ProdBOM, LineNum));
//etc

sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
```

I don't have an adequate form set up currently to test this lookup, so you may need to play around with it in a testing environment, but I have used a similar method in the past.